FastAPI 422 Unprocessable Entity with multiple keys in the body
Whilst migrating an application I'm a little bit confused with the following behaviour of fastapi.
Say I have a simple endpoint:
@router.post("/search")
def search(
    filter: dict = Body(..., embed=False),
) -> list:
    return []

I don't want to embed filter as a top level key.
So I expect the client to look like:
import requests


url = "http://localhost:8090/processes/search"


data = {
    'archived': False,
    'user': 'user@company.io'
    
}

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url=url, json=data, headers=headers)

However I keep getting
422 Unprocessable Entity
{"detail":[{"type":"missing","loc":["body","data"],"msg":"Field required","input":null}]}

This was definitely working before.
Before:

Now all of the request bodies require a top level key:

There's also a new config parameter. Is this related to any pydantic update?
Has anyone seen this?

The endpoint you're looking at the documentation for is not the same as you've defined - adding it by itself to a FastAPI app shows it as expected (most recent fastapi + pydantic), so there's something else going on here. Please add an example that actually reproduces the issue.

Have you seen this answer already?

When embed=False is used, the request body is expected to be in the form {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}. However, with embed=True, the request body should contain a 'filter' key, like this: {"filter": {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}}.
